# How to run sound loops in sequence with pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, tkinter, pygame

I've been experimenting with a weird idea that I got the other day, and I wanted to know if anyone knows a way to solve a problem that I encountered

So, what I wanted to do is a concatenation of sounds that loop a random amount of times and then moves to the next sound, which again loops for another random amount of times and then moves on to the next one and continues doing this for, let's say, 100 other sounds?

It's like a predetermined list of sounds that activates in a fixed order, but each sound has a "looping" variable, which essentially is a random integer between two numbers that determines how many times that sound loops before going to the next one.

I made this animation because I suck at explaining things.

[image]

I know this sounds stupid, pointless and a bit insane, but as I said, it's an experiment.

it seemed easy enough so I tried this:

(Btw I'm using Tkinter and pygame)

```
def activate():

    random_number_1 = randint(0, 3)
    sound1 = pygame.mixer.Sound("sound2.wav")
    pygame.mixer.Sound.play(sound1, random_number_1)

    random_number_2 = randint(0, 3)
    sound2 = pygame.mixer.Sound("sound3.wav")
    pygame.mixer.Sound.play(sound2, random_number_2)

    random_number_3 = randint(0, 3)
    sound3 = pygame.mixer.Sound("sound4.wav")
    pygame.mixer.Sound.play(sound3, random_number_3)

    random_number_4 = randint(0, 3)
    sound4 = pygame.mixer.Sound("sound5.wav")
    pygame.mixer.Sound.play(sound4, random_number_4)

    random_number_5 = randint(0, 3)
    sound5 = pygame.mixer.Sound("sound6.wav")
    pygame.mixer.Sound.play(sound5, random_number_5)


button = Button(root, text="button", command=activate)
button.pack()
```

But the problem is that pygame doesn't wait for each of the loops to end, it plays every sound at the same time

Then, it occurred to me that using "For Loops" might solve the issue, maybe something like this but with sound:

```
def activate():
    randomnumber1 = randint(0, 3)
    for i in range(randomnumber1):
        print(1)

    randomnumber2 = randint(0, 3)
    for i in range(randomnumber2):
        print(2)

    randomnumber3 = randint(0, 3)
    for i in range(randomnumber3):
        print(3)

    randomnumber4 = randint(0, 3)
    for i in range(randomnumber4):
        print(4)
```

like this:

```
def activate():
    randomnumber1 = randint(0, 3)
    for i in range(randomnumber1):
        sound1 = pygame.mixer.Sound("sound2.wav")
        pygame.mixer.Sound.play(sound1)

    randomnumber2 = randint(0, 3)
    for i in range(randomnumber2):
        sound2 = pygame.mixer.Sound("sound3.wav")
        pygame.mixer.Sound.play(sound2)

    randomnumber3 = randint(0, 3)
    for i in range(randomnumber3):
        sound3 = pygame.mixer.Sound("sound4.wav")
        pygame.mixer.Sound.play(sound3)

    randomnumber4 = randint(0, 3)
    for i in range(randomnumber4):
        sound4 = pygame.mixer.Sound("sound5.wav")
        pygame.mixer.Sound.play(sound4)
```

but didn't work

I then remembered that winsound runs synchronously and, as far as I know, you can't specify how many times a sound loops, so I tried:

```
def activate():
    randomnumber1 = randint(0, 3)
    for i in range(randomnumber1):
        winsound.PlaySound("sound2.wav", winsound.SND_ASYNC)

    randomnumber2 = randint(0, 3)
    for i in range(randomnumber2):
        winsound.PlaySound("sound3.wav", winsound.SND_ASYNC)

    randomnumber3 = randint(0, 3)
    for i in range(randomnumber3):
        winsound.PlaySound("sound4.wav", winsound.SND_ASYNC)

    randomnumber4 = randint(0, 3)
    for i in range(randomnumber4):
        winsound.PlaySound("sound5.wav", winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```

but it also didn't work

Now I'm messing around with time.sleep and since each sound has a specific duration, I think I can calculate the time each loop has to wait.

like this, maybe:

sound2.wav lasts for 1.5s so let's say the random number is 2, that's 2 loops of a 1.5s sound clip

2 * 1.5s = 3s

```
random_number_1 = randint(0, 3)
    sound1 = pygame.mixer.Sound("sound2.wav")
    pygame.mixer.Sound.play(sound1, random_number_1)
    time.sleep(random_number_1*1.5)
```

but so far it has been super wonky, messy and weird and the fact that time.sleep freezes Tkinter means it's almost entirely useless for me.

To wrap this up... if you know a way to make pygame sounds behave synchronously or if there's a simpler solution that I'm not seeing, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way of doing this is using the `pygame.mixer.Channel()` function `set_endevent()`.

```
channel2 = pygame.mixer.Channel(1)
channel2.set_endevent( pygame.USEREVENT+1 )
```

This will send your event-queue whatever event you specify (here `pygame.USEREVENT+1` ) when the sound stops playing.

I made a quick demonstration example.  It plays a long background sound, and then a random short-sound continuously.  When the `pygame.USEREVENT+1` event is received, a new sound is started immediately.

```
import pygame
import random

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH    = 400
WINDOW_HEIGHT   = 400
WINDOW_SURFACE  = pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.RESIZABLE

DARK_BLUE = (   3,   5,  54)

### initialisation
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), WINDOW_SURFACE )
pygame.display.set_caption("Random Sound")

### sound
# create separate Channel objects for simultaneous playback
channel1 = pygame.mixer.Channel(0) # argument must be int
channel2 = pygame.mixer.Channel(1)

# define the event that's sent when a sound stops playing:
channel2.set_endevent( pygame.USEREVENT+1 )

# Rain sound from: https://www.freesoundslibrary.com/sound-of-rain-falling-mp3/ (CC BY 4.0)
rain_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound( 'rain-falling.ogg' )
channel1.play( rain_sound, -1 )   # loop the rain sound forever
# and ...  All are (CC BY 4.0)
# https://www.freesoundslibrary.com/car-horn-sound-effect/
# https://www.freesoundslibrary.com/duck-quack/ 
# https://www.freesoundslibrary.com/cash-register-sound-effect/
# https://www.freesoundslibrary.com/turkey-gobble-call/
# https://www.freesoundslibrary.com/single-ding-sound-effect/
# https://www.freesoundslibrary.com/dog-bark-sound-effect/
# 
horn     = pygame.mixer.Sound( 'car-horn2.ogg' )      # converted from MP3 to OGG
quack    = pygame.mixer.Sound( 'duck-quack.ogg' )
ca_ching = pygame.mixer.Sound( 'cash-register.ogg' )
bark     = pygame.mixer.Sound( 'dog-bark.ogg' )
ding     = pygame.mixer.Sound( 'single-ding.ogg' )
gobble   = pygame.mixer.Sound( 'turkey-gobble.ogg' )

# Sound list
all_sounds = [ horn, quack, ca_ching, bark, ding, gobble ]
# Start with a random sound
channel2.play( random.choice( all_sounds ) )

### Main Loop
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False
while not done:

    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True
        elif ( event.type == pygame.USEREVENT+1 ):
            # Channel2 sound ended, start another!
            channel2.play( random.choice( all_sounds ) )
            print( "Sound ended" )

    # Update the window, but not more than 60fps
    window.fill( DARK_BLUE )
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Clamp FPS
    clock.tick_busy_loop(60)

pygame.quit()
```

A lot of the sounds from freesoundslibrary.com are quite long (e.g.: *Multiple* duck-quaks).  I clipped them down to short-sounds with the tool [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/), leaving a split-second of quiet on each side.

**EDIT:**
To change this to a pre-determined list, just keep a record of which is the current_sound.

```
# Sound list
all_sounds = [ horn, quack, ca_ching, bark, ding, gobble ]
# Start with the first sound
channel2.play( all_sounds[ 0 ] )
current_sound_index = 0

...

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True
        elif ( event.type == pygame.USEREVENT+1 ):
            # Channel2 sound ended, start the next sound!
            current_sound_index += 1
            if ( current_sound_index < len( all_sounds ) ):
                channel2.play( all_sounds[ current_sound_index ] )
                print( "Sound ended" )
            else:
                print( "Played all sounds" )
```

Comment: Wow Thank you so much Kingsley, this is incredibly insightful.

I apologize for not being clear enough in my original post, but what I'm trying to do is kind of like a "predetermined" list of sounds in which each sound loops based on a random interval that's associated with the sound that is playing at that time, but Your answer gave me some ideas to try out.
I added a tiny animation to the original post alongside a clearer explanation because I'm so incredibly bad at explaining things.

Thank you again, and I apologize if I misunderstood your answer (I'm not really a programmer)

Comment: No worries, glad I could help.  To make the above example play a pre-determined list, just keep a record of which sound index is being played from  `all_sounds`, then play the *next* one, instead of a random one.

Comment: @Austin.W - Please see edit.  It's a bit closer to what you need.  I think you can work out the random-play-times easily from t his point.

Comment: Well, I can't thank you enough @Kingsley I really appreciate this. Now I'm trying to implement the "loop randomizer", I'm sure I'm going to figure it out eventually Hahaha